# Importing module from "outer" directory [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-import, python-module

I have seen a lot of answers over this simple problem but I can't find a good solution for such, even a workable solution; the problem is, I have this proyect structure

```
parent_folder
   |
   |__folder1
   |    |_____ __init__.py
   |    |_____ file1.py 
   |
   |__folder2
        |_____ __init__.py  
        |_____file2.py
```

I want to call a function (lets name it function2) from file2.py inside file1.py, but when doing an import like this:

```
# inside file1.py

from folder2.file import function2
```

I get the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder2'
```

Then I tried using absolute import, so the code looked like:

```
# inside file1.py

from ..folder2.file2 import function2
```

And I get the following error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

And finally I tried adding such directory to my path using the following code:

```
#inside file1.py

import sys
sys.path.append("..")

from ..folder2.file2 import function2
```

And still, get the same error:

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

What is the definitive CLEAN solution for such problem?,I would appreciate an answer, thanks

**NOTE:** My current Python version is 3.8 and the code is running under Windows 10

Comment: What code did you run to get the error, and what directory is it in? If you are working from the shell, what is your current working directory?

Comment: @tdelaney the code is shown in the description of the problem, are just simple imports; no, im not working from the shell: the current working directory path is:
C:\\Users\\andre\\OneDrive\\Documentos\\Programming\\Python\\codiing\\parent_folder

Answer (score 0):

#### file1.py

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))
from folder2.file2 import function2
```

Comment: Friendly recommendation.  It’s generally better to use `__file__` rather than `os.getcwd()` as the former enables functionality regardless of the current directory.

Comment: But, isnt there a more elegant way rather than doing such lines of code in all files that I want to import?

Comment: Meaning that, I dont want to repeat this lines of code once again and once again:

import os
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.getcwd()))

Comment: Organizing these files in the  `__init__.py`  file is a good practice, just for encoding and finding the root directory.